# Returning a list in a function

Tags: python, list

I realized that return breaks in a function thus I need to find an alternate way to return a modified list.

```
def multiply(lst):
    new = ''
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        var = lst[i] * 3
        new = new + str(var)
    return new
list1 = [1,2,3]
received = multiply(list1)
print [received]
```

I'm trying to multiply all elements by 3 and return (I have to use return). This just gives returns

> ['369']

The list I'm trying to return is

> [3,6,9]

Comment: You want a list, but are appending `str`.

Comment: Do `new = []` and `new.append(str(var))` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `new` isn't a list. In the first line of `multiply()`, you do `new = ''`. This means that `new` is a string.

For strings, the addition operator, `+`, performs *concatenation*. That is to say:

```
'a' + 'b' => 'ab'
```

and similarly:

```
'1' + '2' => '12'
```

or

```
new = ''
new + str(var) => '' + '3' => '3'
```

Clearly, this is not what you want. In order to do what you want, you should construct a *new* list and return it:

```
def multiplyBy3(lst):
    newList = [] #create an empty list
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        newList.append(lst[i] * 3)
    return newList
```

Of course, accessing the list elements by index is not very "pythonic". The rule of thumb is: "unless you need to know the indices of the list elements (which you don't, in this case), iterate over the *values* of the list". We can modify the above function accordingly:

```
def multiplyBy3(lst):
    newList = [] 
    for item in lst: #iterate over the elements of the list
        newList.append(item * 3)
    return newList
```

Finally, python has something called a *[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*, which does the same thing as above, but in a much more concise (and faster) way. This is the preferred method:

```
def multiplyBy3(lst):
    return [item * 3 for item in lst] #construct a new list of item * 3.
```

For more on list comprehensions, see the following tutorial: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/28/python-201-list-comprehensions/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
def multiply(lst):
    return [val*3 for val in lst]

list1 = [1,2,3]
received = multiply(list1)
print received
```

In case you want in-place editing you can to the following:

```
def multiply(lst):
    for idx,val in enumerate(lst):
        lst[idx] = val*3
    return lst
```

The problem in your code that you are merging strings '3', '6' and '9' and return one variable that contains string('369') Than you putting this string in list. That is why you have ['369'] instead of [3,6,9].Please find your code with comments below:

```
def multiply(lst):
    new = '' # new string
    for i in range(len(lst)): # for index in range of list size
        var = lst[i] * 3 # get value from list and mupltiply by 3 and then assign to varible
        new = new + str(var) # append to string new string representation of value calculated in previous row
    return new #return string
```

In any case is a good way to debug your code by putting prints with variable used - though that if you place prints in your code you will understand what is going there

Comment: For inplace it's easier to write `lst[:] = [val*3 for val in lst]`

Comment: @gnibbler Will it be inplace? i thought that [val*3 for val in lst] - left part is a new list - or i am wrong?

Comment: ah I see. [val*3 for val in lst] really confuses me. Probably because I've not learned it yet

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka, it creates the list and then does a slice assignment over the old content

Comment: @Flow this named list comprehension(http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and this is pretty the same like usual for

Comment: @gnibbler ok, i can understand this - but my solution will not require new list right?

Comment: Right, but you can also use a generator expression for the list assinment. `lst[:] = (val*3 for val in lst)`

Comment: @gnibbler ))) ok i see - i like idea with generator - thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> multiply = lambda l: map(lambda x: x*3, l)
>>> multiply([1,2,3])
[3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

easy work...

```
print [3 * x for x in [1, 2, 3]]
```